# Converting double precision floating points from little to big endian

Tags: endianness

I have a file (file.dat) that contains an array of double precision floating points; and a program that reads file.dat as an input and does something with the data contained. The problem though is that this program can only accept big endian but file.dat is little endian.

What can I do to convert the way the double precision floats are stored from little to big endian?

Comment: It might help if you indicated what programming language you're using, and add that language tag to your question.